# Python TypeError: object is not iterable,

Tags: python

I am kinda new to python and trying to create a DTO that minimizes the amount of properties exposed from my api. I use an Azure table storage to get records and then loop over it to create a smaller object omiting properties. Though somewhere in the process I get: "TypeError: 'AbbreviatedPackage' object is not iterable"

In my main I have the follwing call:

```
@app.get("/list/")
def process_results(request: Request, x_api_key: str = Depends(X_API_KEY)):

    packageClient = QueryClient(az_connection_string, "appstoredev")
    results = packageClient.query_packages_storage("PartitionKey eq 'app'")

    return results
```

The query_packages_storage()

```
 def query_packages_storage(self, filter_query):
        from azure.data.tables import TableClient
        table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=self.connection_string, table_name=self.table_name)
        entities = table_client.query_entities(filter_query)

        json_entities = []
        for entity in entities:
            print(entity['ImageUrl'])
            filtered_entity = AbbreviatedPackage(
                entity['ImageUrl'],
                entity['PackageName'],
                entity['DisplayName'],
                entity['Summary']
            )

            json_entities.append(filtered_entity)

        return json.dumps(json_entities)
```

AbbreviatedPackage class

```
class AbbreviatedPackage():

    def __init__(self, image_url, package_name, display_name, summary):
        self.imageUrl = image_url
        self.packageName = package_name
        self.displayName = display_name
        self.summary = summary
```

When I debug the json_entitiesobject gets filled properly
[image]

Any help would be much sppreciated. Cheers

** Edit

I get the errors while being in the loop
[image]

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60027 - "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 373, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 84, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 226, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 161, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 39, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 28, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(func, *args, cancellable=cancellable,
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 805, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 743, in run
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:/source/IlionxCloud/iliona-store-packages/store-packages/main.py", line 49, in process_results
    results = packageClient.query_packages_storage("PartitionKey eq 'app'")
  File "C:\source\IlionxCloud\iliona-store-packages\store-packages\client\AzureTableEntityQueryClient.py", line 39, in query_packages_storage
    for entity in entities:
TypeError: 'AbbreviatedPackage' object is not iterable
```

Comment: *Where* in the process do you get this error, and what are the details of that error?

Comment: thanks for replying, I updated  the post. the error occurs when being in the loop of Entries. also added the stacktrace.

Comment: I believe your issue is with plopping that list of `AbbreviatedPackage` objects into `json.dumps`, which shouldn't work by default. Hopefully my answer at least directs you to the right spot. Do please post actual code inside of backticks next time rather than images--doing it that way makes it much easier for us assisting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `AbbreviatedPackage` object can't be converted to JSON automatically. When you run `json.dumps` with your list of `AbbreviatedPackage` objects they shouldn't be serializable by default, throwing this error (as each object is trying to be iterated over and does not have an `__iter__` method).

A few options:

1. Use the `.__dict__` method for your object when appending to your list. I personally don't like this solution, as it's uncontrolled.
2. Write `__iter__`, `__str__`, and `__repr__` methods to properly serialize to JSON along with a `CustomEncoder` for the `json.dumps` `cls` attribute:

```py
# https://changsin.medium.com/how-to-serialize-a-class-object-to-json-in-python-849697a0cd3#8273

class Label:
    def __init__(self, label, x, y, width, height):
        self.label = label
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def __iter__(self):
        yield {
            "label": self.label,
            "x": self.x,
            "y": self.y,
            "width": self.width,
            "height": self.height
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self, ensure_ascii=False, cls=CustomEncoder)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Reference: https://changsin.medium.com/how-to-serialize-a-class-object-to-json-in-python-849697a0cd3#8273

And the `CustomEncoder` class:

```py
import json

class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(
        self,
        o,
    ):
        """
        A custom default encoder.
        In reality this should work for nearly any iterable.
        """
        try:
            iterable = iter(o)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        else:
            return list(iterable)
        # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

I did a full synthesis on this with code:

- Github: https://github.com/thinkjrs/demo-code/tree/main/json-encode-python-classes
- Blog writeup:  https://thinkjrs.dev/blog/making-python-classes-json-serializable

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, I still used .__dict__ for now but will look into the other options later. Thanks a lot!